# Variable is still null when assigning it a value

Tags: java, android, string

So I have this code:

```
String query = null;

public String createConnection() {

    new NetworkRequest(new ResultFromAsync() {
        @Override
        public void taskCompleted(String result) {
            query = result;
        }
    }).execute();

    return query;
}
```

I am following the MVP design pattern, it is called from my View which upon a Button Click event it calls this method which executes and creates a network request from the Model and then retrieves the JSON as a String, when debugging on line "query = result;" it actually assigns the what is stored in the result variable to the query but when it gets to the line "return query;" it equals to null.

Does anyone understand why it is setting the query to null when it had been assigned to a value of the result variable?

Comment: @laalto So what would be the best approach for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your method that assigns a value to `query` is executed asynchronously, meaning that calling `execute()` won't block the current thread until the asynchronous request completes, but returns immediately. The value of your variable is still `null` at that time. You cannot return a value you don't have yet.

Consider calling the code that requires the value inside the `taskCompleted()` callback.

Comment: `doSomething(result)` - or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: BTW: are you trying to say call the taskCompleted method from my View?

Comment: Both sound like bad ideas. With a static you still don't know when to read it. Let the whatever async framework you're using call the `taskCompleted()` callback when the result is available, and then do whatever you want with the result there.

Comment: & that's exactly what it is doing